# Django Form Field to support US or International phone numbers?

Tags: django, django-forms

I need a Django Form Field to support US or International phone numbers.  Does one exist?  How could you validate US phone #'s or int'l ones.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field

Explaination From the site:

A international phone number field for django that uses 
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/phonenumbers for validation.

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    fax_number = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out Django's "local flavor packages": http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/localflavor/#united-states-of-america-us

Comment: Can you create a field that will validate US or Int'l #'s at the same time?

Comment: Not out of the box, you would have to make your own field class or use a regex field as mentioned here! Subclassing an exisiting field and overriding it's clean method shouldn't be the big deal, look at this example: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/localflavor/us/forms.py#L29

Comment: Local flavor packages were removed/deprecated in 1.5 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#django-contrib-localflavor

Answer (score 1):

lazerscience's answer is correct, but I want to give an alternative as you also asked for International Phone Numbers.

Just use a [RegexField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#regexfield) with a regular expression for the format you want, for the most types of phone numbers this can easily be googled. In fact, many local flavor fields are based on a RegexField.

But use the Local Flavor packages if it suits all your needs!